# How to store and format data properly in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to use the [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org) Library and make the data displayed in the graph dependent on what a user has entered.

Right now I am not quite sure how to get the data in the right format so that I can use if for the library.

Currently I have a problem when combining the labels and values so that it matches the right index for the right label.
I am having a table with **two values ( A Month (Specified as Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr.etc.) and a numeric Value)**

Now I need to combine months that appear twice and add the values associated with each month. I dont really know if I should use a 2d Array or 2 arrays for this. 
For example

```
var labels = ["Jan 17", "Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17", "Mar 17"];
var values = [10,10,25,40,100];
```

becomes

```
var newlabels = ["Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17"];
var newvalues = [20,25,140];
```

or as 2D Array:

```
var graphdata = [["Jan 17", 10],["Jan 17",10],["Feb 17",25],["Mar 17",40],["Mar 17",100]];
```

becomes

```
var newgraphData =[["Jan 17", 20],["Feb 17",25],["Mar 17",140]];
```

Either way is fine but I dont know which to use. Also I wouldn't quite know how to get the data in a 2d Array with jQuery selectors and the .map() function.

I was thinking of using the .map() and .reduce() function with a loop to go through each index but I cant quite seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why not `[{ 'label': 'Jan 17', val: '100'}, ....]`?

Comment: Well yea that could work, but how would I combine the duplicate labels and add the associated numeric values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You will get the formatted data in the arrays `rLabels` and `rValues`.

```
var labels = ["Jan 17", "Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17", "Mar 17"]
  , values = [10, 10, 25, 40, 100]
  , rLabels = []
  , rValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var label = labels[i];
    var ind = rLabels.indexOf(label);
    if (ind == -1) {
        rLabels.push(label);
        rValues.push(values[i]);
    } else {
        rValues[ind] += values[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` consumes linear time – grouping with Map can be done in logarithmic time.

Comment: Thank this works totally fine. @naomik how would you use map there?

Answer (score 1):

```
const labels = ["Jan 17", "Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17", "Mar 17"];
const values = [10,10,25,40,100];

const result = labels.map((label, i) => ({label, value: values[i]}));
const grouped = []

result.forEach(o => {
  if (!this[o.label]) {
    this[o.label] = { label: o.label, value: 0 };
    grouped.push(this[o.label]);
  }
  this[o.label].value += o.value;
}, {});
console.log(grouped) // [ { label: 'Jan 17', value: 20 }, { label: 'Feb 17', value: 25 }, { label: 'Mar 17', value: 140 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that aims to deconstruct the problem into smaller parts. Once we have a couple functions to transform data in a high-level way, assembling the final result becomes a trivial task.

We can start with a way to combine your two lists in a *zipper*-like fashion, using `zip`

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const zip = ([ x = None, ...xs ], [ y = None, ...ys ]) =>
  x === None || y === None
    ? []
    : [ [ x, y ] ] .concat (zip (xs, ys))

const labels =
  [ "Jan 17", "Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17", "Mar 17" ]

const values =
  [ 10, 10, 25, 40, 100 ]

console.log (zip (labels, values))
// [ [ 'Jan 17', 10 ]
// , [ 'Jan 17', 10 ]
// , [ 'Feb 17', 25 ]
// , [ 'Mar 17', 40 ]
// , [ 'Mar 17', 100 ] 
// ]
```

With a list of `[ key, value ]` pairs, we can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that groups values by `key`. Maps are lightning fast thanks to [logarithmic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). JavaScript gives us Map, so when applicable, it's best to use it instead of a plain Object. At the very least, avoid using `Array.prototype.indexOf` like one answer suggests as it uses [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Linear_search) and not suitable for larger data sets.

```
const group = (xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce ((acc, [ key, value ]) =>
    acc.has (key)
      ? acc.set (key, value + acc.get (key))
      : acc.set (key, value),
    new Map ())

console.log (group (zip (labels, values)))
// => Map { 'Jan 17' => 20, 'Feb 17' => 25, 'Mar 17' => 140 }
```

Lastly, we can convert from a Map to your desired output type using  [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [Map.prototype.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)

```
const main = (labels = [], values = []) =>
  Array.from (group (zip (labels, values)) .entries ())
```

Here's a functioning example

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const zip = ([ x = None, ...xs ], [ y = None, ...ys ]) =>
  x === None || y === None
    ? []
    : [ [ x, y ] ] .concat (zip (xs, ys))
  
const group = (xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce ((acc, [ key, value ]) =>
    acc.has (key)
      ? acc.set (key, value + acc.get (key))
      : acc.set (key, value),
    new Map ())

const main = (labels = [], values = []) =>
  Array.from (group (zip (labels, values)) .entries ())

const labels =
  [ "Jan 17", "Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17", "Mar 17" ]
  
const values =
  [ 10, 10, 25, 40, 100 ]

console.log (main (labels, values))
// [ [ 'Jan 17', 20 ]
// , [ 'Feb 17', 25 ]
// , [ 'Mar 17', 140 ]
// ]
```